# Meta Query compare if meta key is in specified range

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Posts have a price custom meta field associated with them. On frontend, there is an option to search a post by specifying a price range, such as all posts that's 'price' value is bigger than 1 AND smaller than 10.

Management decided that we have no option to use WooCommerce for whatever out-of-earth reason, so we have to use native Wordpress for this.

This is what I've managed to do as of now as the arguements of get_`posts($args)`

```
$args=array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => 1,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            )
        );
```

But this only returns posts where 'price' is bigger than 1. I need to have posts which's 'price' field is bigger than 1 AND at the same time smaller than 10.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$args=array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'price',
                       'value' => array(1,10),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                    )
                )
            );
```